# Are there any named probability distribution of $x$ proportional to $e^{-\alpha x}(1-e^{-x})^{\beta -1}$?

Tags: probability-distributions

Are there any named probability distribution of $x$ like:

$$
Pr(x)=\frac{\Gamma(\alpha+\beta)} {\Gamma(\alpha)\Gamma(\beta)} e^{-\alpha x}(1-e^{-x})^{\beta -1}
$$
where $x\in(0,\infty), \alpha>0,\beta >0$. In particular I would like to have an analytical expression of the mean and variance of $Pr(x)$ in terms of $\alpha$ and $\beta$.

Note that the transformation $y(x)=e^{-x}$ yields a beta distribution with parameters $\alpha$ and $\beta$.

Comment: Should the $(1-e^x)^{\beta-1}$ be $(1-e^{-x})^{\beta-1}$?

Comment: @Carl yes, your are right, negative exponent. edited

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is, unsurprisingly, called a *beta exponential distribution* (although I'm not sure it's a widely used distribution, so this name may not be as canonical as one might hope). [Nadarajah and Kotz](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0951832005001316) define this distribution given parameters $(\lambda,a,b)$ as having probability density function
$$f(x)=\frac{\lambda}{B(a,b)}e^{-b\lambda x}\left(1-e^{-\lambda x}\right)^{a-1},$$
so your distribution has parameters $(1,\beta,\alpha)$. They show that, if $X$ is a random variable following this distribution,
$$\mathbb E[X^n]=\frac{(-1)^n}{\lambda^n B(a,b)}\frac{\partial^n}{\partial p^n}B(a,1+p-a)\bigg|_{p=a+b-1},$$
which allows you to calculate the mean and variance. The linked article gives many more calculations of standard properties of this distribution, which may be of interest.

Comment: I seems the answer to me. I started from the beta distribution of $y(x)$ with parameters $(\alpha,\beta)$, so am double checking my derivation, and the linked article.